# Where should jspm_packages go in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core, jspm

I'm developing with `ASP.NET Core`, and am using `jspm`, with *Visual Studio 2017 RC* and *WebStorm*.

It seems that `jspm init` expects your absolute lowest level, root folder with EVERYTHING is always going to be `wwwroot`, and thus the path it establishes (and even more rigidly enforces in `jspm 0.17.x beta) is`wwwroot/jspm_packages`

However, a new `ASP.NET Core` project sets up with the `node_modules` directory, and by proxy the `packages.json` file, just outside of `wwwroot`.

Obviously, I can move the file - but it puzzles me that they're different. Some people say *"just use a gulp task"* but that isn't really an option. I tried that route and it was a complete nightmare to maintain. Plus, `jspm` seems to load things directly from its package store by default.

So which is it? Is there an inherit problem with the `jspm_packages` folder being a sibling to the `wwwroot` folder? Using the `UseStaticFiles` option in the configuration allows me to specify access to folders outside of `wwwroot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wwwroot is your public folder, this way, all your assets must be inside of it.

You can configure npm to install modules inside wwwroot folder. Take a look in this [config page](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) from npm documentation.

However, I recommend you to put your files outside the wwwroot folder, and then, send to wwwroot only the files you're gonna use.

Grunt and Gulp are very simple and useful. If you want to give it a try, take a look in this [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular). There you can find an example of how to use Grunt with VisualStudio

Comment: I did use gulp and it was an awful experience. I had a very large build and it worked as long as the absolute most infinitesimal thing never changed. I don't see any possible way I would use it again.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't like Gulp/Grunt, then you should put your files inside wwwroot. In big projects they're very useful (compile css, concat/minify js files, so on).

Comment: The problem I ran into was that it became almost impossible to keep the environment in sync with gulp/grunt. So many things had to be considered, so often, with such tiny details making huge differences in the way other things interacted (pathing for modules by systemjs, for instance. Image pathing. Font pathing. css pathing).

In the end, it was just easier to hand copy and paste hundreds of files every time something changed than to use gulp. It was really cool at first, but the moment you tried to use any package that wasn't laid out exactly like something else wanted it, it collapsed.